# numpy array, delete row if one string element is repeated in another row

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
vals = numpy.array([['user1','number1','grades1'],
                    ['user1', 'number2','grade2'], 
                    ['user3', 'number3','grade3'], 
                    ['user4', 'number4','grade4']])
```

And I would like to delete one whole row containing `user1` because is repeated (it doesnt matter which row may be) in another row at the first column. Also if there are more rows displaying `user1`, just keep the first one found.  so the output can be something like:

```
array([['user1', 'number1','grade1'], 
       ['user3', 'number3','grade3'], 
       ['user4', 'number4','grade4']])
```

So far I tried:

```
a = (vals[0:1,0:1] == vals[1:2,0:1])
vals = numpy.delete(vals, numpy.where(a), axis=0)
```

However, how can I use this making a loop?

Comment: What if there's one more occurrence of `user1`, which row(s) is/are to be deleted then? Every row except the last one? Consider adding such a case in the sample data?

Comment: If there are more occurrences of `user1`, I would go for except the first one, or last one. In my assignment. that is not mentioned very clear so I guess its open. I only need to find the occurrences and keep only one row...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.unique` which can also return indices.

```
unique_user,unique_indices = numpy.unique(vals[:,0],return_index = True)
unique_vals = vals[unique_indices]
```